# Quosures in R, how to use the !! operator (tidy-evaluation)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm trying to understand  tidy evaluation in R.

```
grouped_mean <- function(data, group_var, summary_var) {
    group_var <- enquo(group_var)
    summary_var <- enquo(summary_var)

    data %>%
        group_by(!!group_var) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(!!summary_var))
}
```

I understand why and how to use it but not what actually happens I guess.

```
var <- "test"
var <- enquo(var)
!!var 

Error in is_quosure(e2) : argument "e2" is missing, with no default
```

This gives me an error while I expected it to work  outside `dplyr` too. Why does it not work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` is an unquoting operator that only works in *quoting context*, i.e. in arguments to dplyr verbs. The error message you're seeing with `!!quo(foo)` is a bug in the current CRAN release. With the development version, it is now:

```
Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

  # Bad:
  list(!!myquosure)

  # Good:
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Finally, note that `enquo()` should only be used to quote function arguments. For technical reasons having to do with the R compiler, it still works on other objects, but won't do what you expect. You should only use it within a function, and only with argument names of that function.