# Can this for-loop be vectorized

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, chi-squared

I implemented a chi-square test in R using a for-loop in order to calculate the test statistic for every cell. However, I was wondering whether this can be optimized. And is the chi=square in R working as my code?

```
eval_preds <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  cells <- unique(df[,groups])
  my_sum = 0

  # compute test statistic for every cell
  for (i in 1:length(cells)) {

    # get cell means
    m_obs <- mean(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    m_pred <- mean(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])

    # get cell variance
    var_obs <- var(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    var_pred <- var(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])

    # get cell's number of observations
    N_obs <- length(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    N_pred <- length(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])

    # sum up
    my_sum = my_sum + (m_obs-m_pred) / ((var_obs/N_obs) + (var_pred/N_pred))
  }
  return(my_sum)
}
```

And a toy example:

```
# save this as df_head.csv
"RT","RTmodel_s","groups"
899,975.978308710825,"pl_sgDom"
1115,1095.61538562629,"sg_sgDom"
1077,1158.19266217845,"pl_sgDom"
850,996.410033287249,"sg_plDom"
854,894.862587823602,"pl_sgDom"
1720,1046.34200941684,"sg_sgDom"

# load dat into R
df <- read.csv('./df_head.csv')

my_chi <- eval_preds(df, 'RT', 'Pred', 'Group')
```

EDIT

The function eval_preds function is called in a for loop in which different predictions are computed based on a free parameter t_parsing.

```
p_grid = seq(0,1,0.1)

# tune p
for (i in 1:length(p_grid)) {
  
  # set t_parsing
  t_parsing = p_grid[i]
  
  # compute model-time RTs
  df$RTmodel <- ifelse(df$number == 'sing', 
                             RT_lookup(df$sg_t_act, df$epsilon), 
                             RT_decompose(df$sg_t_act, df$pl_t_act, df$epsilon))
  
  # scale into real time
  df$RTmodel_s <- scale_RTmodel(df$RT, df$RTmodel)
  
  # compare model output to measured RT
  # my_chi <- eval_preds(my_nouns, 'RT', 'RTmodel_s', 'groups')
  my_chi <- eval_preds1(df, RT, RTmodel_s, groups) #function written by DaveArmstrong
  print(paste(p_grid[i], ': ', my_chi))
}
```

`RT` and `RTmodel_s` are numerical variables, `groups` is a character variable.

Comment: why don't you use the built in `chisq.test`?

Comment: I don't know whether it performs the same calculations

Comment: @hyhno01 It's a bit silly to trust some `R` functions and not others, but if you insist, then download the source code for `chisq.test` and examine it for yourself.

Comment: FWIW, you could make all your temp variables (`m_obs m_pred` etc) into vectors and then perform the `my_sum` calculation outside the loop.

Comment: @starja, the built-in chisq.test does not operate on groups-level as far as I can see. So the problem is not the built-in function per se, but how it can be applied on different groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could do it with `dplyr` and `rlang`:

```
eval_preds <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  require(dplyr)
  require(rlang)
  groups <- enquo(groups)
  observations <- enquo(observations)
  predictions <- enquo(predictions)
  out <- DF %>% 
    group_by(!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(m_obs = mean(!!observations), 
              m_pred = mean(!!predictions), 
              var_obs = var(!!observations), 
              var_pred = var(!!predictions),
              N_obs = sum(!is.na(!!observations)),
              N_pred = sum(!is.na(!!predictions))) %>% 
    mutate(my_sum = (m_obs - m_pred)/((var_obs/N_obs) + (var_pred/N_pred))) 
sum(out$my_sum)
}
my_chi <- eval_preds(DF, RT, Pred, Group) 
my_chi
# [1] 1.6
```

Or, even a bit more streamlined:

```
eval_preds <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  require(dplyr)
  require(rlang)
  groups <- enquo(groups)
  observations <- enquo(observations)
  predictions <- enquo(predictions)
  out <- DF %>% 
    group_by(!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(diff= mean(!!observations) - mean(!!predictions), 
              sum_v = (var(!!observations)/n()) + (var(!!predictions)/n())) %>% 
    mutate(my_sum = diff/sum_v) 
  sum(out$my_sum)
}
my_chi <- eval_preds(DF, RT, Pred, Group) 
my_chi
# [1] 1.6
```

---

**EDIT** - added benchmarks

So, I think the question of which one is better depends on the size of the data set.  I also want to throw one more function into the mix - one that uses `by()` from base R:

```
eval_preds <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  cells <- unique(df[,groups])
  my_sum = 0
  
  # compute test statistic for every cell
  for (i in 1:length(cells)) {
    
    # get cell means
    m_obs <- mean(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    m_pred <- mean(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])
    
    # get cell variance
    var_obs <- var(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    var_pred <- var(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])
    
    # get cell's number of observations
    N_obs <- length(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], observations])
    N_pred <- length(df[df[,groups] == cells[i], predictions])
    
    # sum up
    my_sum = my_sum + (m_obs-m_pred) / ((var_obs/N_obs) + (var_pred/N_pred))
  }
  return(my_sum)
}

eval_preds1 <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  require(dplyr)
  require(rlang)
  groups <- enquo(groups)
  observations <- enquo(observations)
  predictions <- enquo(predictions)
  out <- df %>% 
    group_by(!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(m_obs = mean(!!observations), 
              m_pred = mean(!!predictions), 
              var_obs = var(!!observations), 
              var_pred = var(!!predictions),
              N_obs = sum(!is.na(!!observations)),
              N_pred = sum(!is.na(!!predictions))) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(my_sum = (m_obs - m_pred)/((var_obs/N_obs) + (var_pred/N_pred))) 
  sum(out$my_sum)
}

eval_preds2 <- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  require(dplyr)
  require(rlang)
  groups <- enquo(groups)
  observations <- enquo(observations)
  predictions <- enquo(predictions)
  out <- df %>% 
    group_by(!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(diff= mean(!!observations) - mean(!!predictions), 
              sum_v = (var(!!observations)/n()) + (var(!!predictions)/n())) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(my_sum = diff/sum_v) 
  sum(out$my_sum)
}

eval_preds3<- function(df, observations, predictions, groups) {
  # determine cells
  
  m <- by(df[,c(observations, predictions)], list(df[[groups]]), function(x)diff(-colMeans(x)))
  v <- by(df[,c(observations, predictions)], list(df[[groups]]), function(x)sum(apply(x, 2, var)/nrow(x)))
  sum(m/v)
}
```

So, `eval_preds()` is the original, `eval_preds1()` is the first set of `dplyr` code and `eval_preds2()`, `eval_preds3()` is the base R with `by()`. On the original data set, here is the output from `microbenchmark()`.

```
microbenchmark(eval_preds(DF, 'RT', 'Pred', 'Group'), 
               eval_preds1(DF, RT, Pred, Group), 
               eval_preds2(DF, RT, Pred, Group), 
               eval_preds4(DF, 'RT', 'Pred', 'Group'), times=100)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                  expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval  cld
#  eval_preds(DF, "RT", "Pred", "Group")  236.513  279.4920  324.9760  295.190  321.0125   774.213   100 a   
#       eval_preds1(DF, RT, Pred, Group) 5236.850 5747.5095 6503.0251 6089.343 6937.8670 12950.677   100    d
#       eval_preds2(DF, RT, Pred, Group) 4871.812 5372.2365 6070.7297 5697.686 6548.8935 14577.786   100   c 
# eval_preds4(DF, "RT", "Pred", "Group")  651.013  739.9405  839.1706  773.610  923.9870  1582.218   100  b
```

In this case, the original code is the fastest.  However, if we made a bigger dataset - here's one with 1000 groups and 10 observations per group.

```
DF2 <- data.frame(
  Group = rep(1:1000, each=10), 
  RT = rpois(10000, 3), 
  Pred = rpois(10000, 4)
)
```

The output from `microbenchmark()` here tells a quite different story.

```
microbenchmark(eval_preds(DF2, 'RT', 'Pred', 'Group'), 
               eval_preds1(DF2, RT, Pred, Group), 
               eval_preds2(DF2, RT, Pred, Group), 
               eval_preds3(DF2, 'RT', 'Pred', 'Group'), times=25)


# Unit: milliseconds
#                                   expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#  eval_preds(DF2, "RT", "Pred", "Group") 245.67280 267.96445 353.6489 324.29416 419.4193 565.4494    25   c
#       eval_preds1(DF2, RT, Pred, Group)  74.56522  88.15003 102.6583  92.24103 106.6766 211.2368    25 a  
#       eval_preds2(DF2, RT, Pred, Group)  79.00919  89.03754 125.8202  94.71703 114.5176 606.8830    25 a  
# eval_preds3(DF2, "RT", "Pred", "Group") 193.94042 240.35447 272.0004 254.85557 316.5098 420.5394    25  b
```

Both `dplyr()` based functions are much faster than their base R competitors.  So, the question of which is the "optimal" method depends on the size of the problem to be solved.

Comment: This is *different* code, but is it *optimized*?  My guess is that the OP is looking for greater speed; perhaps you could post up a `microbenchmark`  test comparing your two solutions with his original code

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for the suggestion - I added the benchmarks to the answer.

Comment: Very nice!   The results suggest significant "setup time" for the solutions which turned out to be faster for larger datasets.

Comment: I agree with the use of grouping to solve this - the loop with the filter is somewhat redundant. However, the benchmarking is off because the ```dplyr``` functions use ```DF``` instead of ```df```. That is, the ```dplyr``` is always operating on the smaller dataset.

Comment: Thanks, @Cole.  I updated the functions to use `df` instead of `DF`.  Same result, though less dramatic. On average, the `dplyr` functions are about 2.5 to 3 times faster than the base R functions.

Comment: Great, thanks for the elaborated answer with the benchmark. My dataset is much bigger than the toydata described here. So I will use your optimized dplyr-based function! Great help!

Comment: @DaveArmstrong unfortunately, when I run the code like ```my_chi <- eval_preds1(my_nouns, RT, RTmodel_s, groups)``` I receive the error message depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671851/quosures-in-r-how-to-use-the-operator-tidy-evaluation). I cannot fix it. What's the problem?

Comment: @hyhno01 without seeing the actual data and all of the code you used to produce the result, it is difficult to know what is going wrong.  Could you post it as an edit to the question?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong can you determine the problem now?

Comment: @hyhno01 to really troubleshoot it, I would need the actual data in `df` and `p_grid`.  Could you post those, too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221450/discussion-between-hyhno01-and-davearmstrong).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base approach that should look very similar to your loop. Note, the loop is inefficient because each loop it is looking at each group for filtering. Grouping operations, such as `by()` will help because we only have to scan through the grouping variable once to get the groupings.

```r
DF <- read.table(header=T, text="Group    Pred    RT
cond1       2        3
cond1       4        2
cond2       2        2
cond2       1        2")

stats = by(data = DF[c("Pred", "RT")], 
           INDICES = DF["Group"],
           simplify = FALSE,
           FUN = function(DF_grp) {
             RT = DF_grp[["RT"]]
             Pred = DF_grp[["Pred"]]
             
             m_obs = mean(RT)
             m_pred = mean(Pred)
             
             var_obs = var(RT)
             var_pred = var(Pred)
             
             N_obs = N_pred = length(Pred) ##simplification
             
             return((m_obs - m_pred) / ((var_obs / N_obs) + (var_pred / N_pred)))
           }
)
           
stats
#> Group: cond1
#> [1] -0.4
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> Group: cond2
#> [1] 2

sum(unlist(stats, use.names = FALSE))
#> [1] 1.6
```

Finally, if you know that your grouping is ordered, you can look into `Rcpp` for additional performance.