# How do I create a variable recording whether any members of a group possess from characteristic in R?

Tags: r

Good day,

I have a panel data set that contains a few thousand pairs (dyads); each panel contains 23 years with over 500k observations. The dependent variable, Value26, is the value of trade exchanged between the two countries (coded as pair).

What I want to do (which I can do in Stata) is create a categorical variable that is 0 if no trade is conducted within the panel and 1 if at least one year of trade is exchanged by the pair (as I would like to exclude those pairs when no trade occurs when I run the regression).

Below is an example from my data set, which shows NoTrade26 having a 1 because there was at least 1 year between pair 9.

```
| year | pair | Value26  | NoTrade26 |
|------|------|----------|-----------|
| 2014 |    8 |        0 |         0 |
| 2015 |    8 |        0 |         0 |
| 2016 |    8 |        0 |         0 |
| 2017 |    8 |        0 |         0 |
| 2018 |    8 |        0 |         0 |
| 2002 |    9 | 25.17931 |         1 |
| 2004 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2005 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2006 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2007 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2008 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2009 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2010 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2011 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2012 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2013 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2015 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
| 2017 |    9 |        0 |         1 |
```

Could anyone suggest how to code this in R? I've toyed around with the code for a few hours, but nothing is coming to me on how to do this in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
~year , ~pair , ~Value26  , ~NoTrade26 ,
2014 ,    8 ,        0 ,         0 ,
2015 ,    8 ,        0 ,         0 ,
2016 ,    8 ,        0 ,         0 ,
2017 ,    8 ,        0 ,         0 ,
2018 ,    8 ,        0 ,         0 ,
2002 ,    9 , 25.17931 ,         1 ,
2004 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2005 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2006 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2007 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2008 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2009 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2010 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2011 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2012 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2013 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2015 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 ,
2017 ,    9 ,        0 ,         1 )

library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(pair) %>% 
  mutate(NoTrade26 = as.numeric(!all(Value26 == 0)))

# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   pair [2]
#     year  pair Value26 NoTrade26
#    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   2014     8     0           0
# 2   2015     8     0           0
# 3   2016     8     0           0
# 4   2017     8     0           0
# 5   2018     8     0           0
# 6   2002     9    25.2         1
# 7   2004     9     0           1
# 8   2005     9     0           1
# 9   2006     9     0           1
# 10  2007     9     0           1
# 11  2008     9     0           1
# 12  2009     9     0           1
# 13  2010     9     0           1
# 14  2011     9     0           1
# 15  2012     9     0           1
# 16  2013     9     0           1
# 17  2015     9     0           1
# 18  2017     9     0           1
```

Comment: It worked, I think; I'm confused as to how to add this new variable to the data.frame itself?

Comment: Nevermind; I figured it out! :) Thanks @DaveArmstrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
base_method <- function(data){
  aggs <- suppressWarnings(aggregate(Value26 ~ pair, data, any))
  data$NoTrade26 <- as.numeric(aggs$Value26[match(data$pair, aggs$pair)])
  data
}

dplyr_method <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(pair) %>% 
    mutate(NoTrade26 = as.numeric(!all(Value26 == 0)))
}

> identical(base_method(data), dplyr_method(data))
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base_method(data),
  dplyr_method(data)
)

Unit: microseconds
               expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  base_method(data)  741.879  818.234  931.1464  876.283  925.427  4489.42   100
 dplyr_method(data) 2476.527 2623.961 3006.0032 2776.064 3037.870 10767.17   100
```

Comment: I've seen this happen elsewhere, too.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63849591/can-this-for-loop-be-vectorized/63850349#63850349) answer, you can see benchmarks for different sizes of data where the base R methods are faster on small datasets, but the `dplyr()` method is faster on bigger datasets. Might be the same here.

Comment: In fact, I just did it with a dataset with 23000 rows (23 rows each for 1000 group) and the dplyr method is about 9 times faster than the base method on average.